# Android M App links: unknown autoVerify attribute

Tags: android, android-manifest

Integrating [App Links](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/app-linking.html) into my app, I put this code to AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="@string/deep_link_scheme" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="<my host>" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="<my host>" />
</intent-filter>
```

Setting

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
targetSdkVersion 22
```

I have compile time error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'autoVerify' in package 'android'
```

What is correct workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [setting up the Android M SDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#update), you must compile and target M specifically:

> - compileSdkVersion is set to `'android-MNC'`
> - minSdkVersion is set to `'MNC'`
> - targetSdkVersion is set to `'MNC'`

Comment: Oops, missed that. Thanks!